# Type only interfaces

Tags: programming-languages, dsl

Does anyone happen to know if a program concept exits in a language that allows for the construction of interfaces that only specify the required **data types** needed  to satisfy it's implementation?

In other words, the naming conventions of the object/class implementing it are irrelevant. Successful implementation is based on whether or not, the property types comprise to satisfy the interface's type definition requirements.

For example, suppose I had a program that created a bunch of type aliases. I'd like to potentially do this:

```
# Revenue of the transaction
type Revenue = Float

# Id of the Transaction
type TransactionId = String

interface Transaction {
  Revenue
  TransactionId
}

# This compiles...
type MyCustomTransaction implements Transaction {
   saleAmount: Revenue
   id: TransactionId
   myCustomProperty: Boolean
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is a less useful version of protocols or abstract classes which define a required interface. By just defining the type and not requiring the name be defined the interface is useless.

Think about it like this. I tell you that some object complies with the `Transaction` interface. You only know that the object contains a property that is a `Revenue` and a `TransactionId`. However you do not know how to access them and what they mean. So can you even use the interface?

There is an idea similar to what you are saying like typed-tuples, which are groups of elements that are not necessarily named like (5,5,"Hello") which is of type (Int,Int,String). However since a tuple is ordered, knowing the type provides an "implicit" interface in that you know the amount and types of elements contained.

Here is some more reading on protocols and abstract classes if you are interested: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_type

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concept_(generic_programming)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_(object-oriented_programming)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I think in this system, the types would have to all be unique (as they would if they were the key names). Will take a look at the links, thanks again.

Comment: Check out what a C/C++ union is. It's a data structure where it's only as big as the largest member so you can interpret the union differently based on what you think it has